# Unable to load DLL 'IfxMetrics.dll': The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, instrumentation

I am getting weird dll missing error following is my scenario

I have two projects One console application another is C# class library(logger) project
In class library project i am using some of the Microsoft instrumentation frame work related functionality(MdmMetricWriter) , i have installed the nuget Microsoft.Cloud.InstrumentationFramework in class library this class library is used by many applications in company.
when i try to call the log method from console application i get the Unable to load DLL 'IfxMetrics.dll': The specified module could not be found error even though it's nuget already installed in class library
if i install same nuget in the console application it works but i don't want to do this and create dependency of this dll in all caller applications please help me to resolve this

Comment: Did you try uninstall and reinstall the Nuget package in the class library?

Comment: Check your dependencies. If your class library depend on `IfxMetrics.dll` and your console application depend on that class library, then `IfxMetrics.dll` must be copied (by Visual Studio at build process) to output directory of your console application project. Can you look if `IfxMetrics.dll` is in output dir?

Comment: @ vaisly  The class library project is added as project reference in the console application

Comment: @zhao i tried reinstalling still the same problem